# Alamofire integration with XCode 8 Beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, swift3

I'm trying to add Alamofire in XCode 8 Beta 6. I have Cocoapods 1.1.0.beta.2 and I'm using this pod:

## platform :ios, '9.0'

target ‘TestProject’ do

use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire',
    :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
    :branch => 'swift3’

end

When I run pod install it seems like everything is ok. However, when I try and build the project, several errors in the Alamofire code occur. Most of them are of type: "@escaping attribute only applies to function types"
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with XCode itself. When I downloaded the newest XCode version - XCode GM, no more errors were present.